# Linking a shared library with another shared lib in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a shared library. Let us say `libabc.so`. It uses another `.so` file , say `lib123.so` (a lib in `/usr/local/lib`). Now I am using my shared lib `libabc.so` in my application. Say `my-app`. I want to know how I should link these binaries? I don't want to link `my-app` with `lib123.so` directly. `my-app` should be linked with only `libabc.so`. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance. I am using `g++` compiler.

Comment: have you thought about using an atuomated build system, for example autotools? autotools comes with libtool, which takes most of the awkward processing required to build shared libraries away.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: you are wrong in advising to link with a static `lib122.a` the shared  `libabc.so`

Comment: Show your exact build commands (for the object files and the shared library).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Suppose that `libabc.so` is obtained from [posiition independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) object code files `abc1.pic.o` and `abc2.pic.o` ; then you have built them with e.g.

```
 gcc -Wall -fPIC -O -g abc1.c -c -o abc1.pic.o
 gcc -Wall -fPIC -O -g abc2.c -c -o abc2.pic.o
```

and you build `libabc.so` with

```
gcc -shared  abc1.pic.o  abc2.pic.o -L/usr/local/lib -l123 -o libabc.so
```

<sup>I added `-L/usr/local/lib` *before* `-l123` because I am assuming you have a `/usr/local/lib/lib123.so` shared library.</sup>

Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

As you see, you may link a shared library `lib123.so` into your own shared library `libabc.so`

Then check with `ldd libabc.so`

You may want to set up some [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) in your `libabc.so` by adding `-Wl,-rpath` and `-Wl,$RPATHDIR` to the linking command.

For much more details, read Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

PS. Don't use a static library for `lib123.a` (it should be PIC). If you link non-PIC code into a shared object, you lose most of the advantages of shared objects, and the dynamic linker [ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) has to do zillions of relocations.

Comment: I had done exactly the same thing you mentioned here. But when i do a ldd on libabc.so , it is not listing lib123.so. Do you know why it is like that?

Comment: Why not a static library for lib123? What if it is not PIC?

Comment: I cannot help, unless you **show** at least the **precise commands** involved in building your `abc*.pic.o` objects and the `libabc.so` library.

Comment: @BЈовић: Because static libraries are non-PIC in general, and are basically a catenation of member object files.

Comment: Please edit your question. And tell there *exactly* how you build both `abc.pic.o` and `libabc.so`

Comment: g++ -Wall -fPIC -O -g abc.cpp -c -o abc.pic.o                      g++ -shared  abc.pic.o -L. -l123 -o libabc.so  Is it right?         When i do a ldd on libabc.so i didnt see lib123.so

Comment: Please, please **edit your question**. Your comments above are nearly unreadable!

Comment: sorry i am not able to edit that comment. i cant find lib123.so while i do an ldd on libabc.so

Comment: You probably should be able to edit your own initial [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19424494/841108) (not the comments).

Comment: g++ -Wall -fPIC -O -g abc.cpp -c -o abc.pic.o

Comment: g++ -shared abc.pic.o -L. -l123 -o libabc.so

Comment: I don't understand why you put `-L.`; you probably want `-L/usr/local/lib` instead.

Comment: i made a lib123.so just to test. it is in current folder

Comment: If linking with non -fPIC compiled files work then the loader will have to do a lot of relocations BUT once once and not on each function call or global variable use. This can speed up the executable quite a lot 10% in average to 20% in special cases. Because it reduces lots of cache misses caused by indirection.

Comment: I almost lost hope, but then I saw comment from 
@luighi-anthony-vitón-zorrilla
`in some versions of gcc the order where library references are placed, is important`

So keeping -l<libname> end of gcc command solved the issue of linking and thats already a real bad feeling working with gcc verion 8.4.0.. Why should order of param change behavior of outcome..

Comment: Hello Basile, I have a similar issue and using `-fPIC` does not fix it, could you have a look at this question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603457/c-linux-lib1-use-lib2-main-uses-lib1-why-shall-it-be-linked-to-lib2?

Answer (score 2):

When trying to create my own shared library that uses Berkeley DB, I found that I have to put the -ldb at the end of the gcc command or else it blew up saying the symbol 'db_create' was not found.  This was under Cygwin.

Specifically, this worked:

> gcc -shared -o $b/$libfile nt_*.o -ldb

This did not work:

> gcc -ldb -shared -o $b/$libfile nt_*.o

Answer (score 2):

Following the same procedure pointed out by [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/5107192), for example, I have a library which depends on `libm.so`, so the compilation for the library objects are:

```
gcc -fPIC -Wall -g -I include -I src -c src/wavegen.c  -o build/arm/wavegen.o                                                                                          
gcc -fPIC -Wall -g -I include -I src -c src/serial.c  -o build/arm/serial.o
```

To compile the library, however, in some versions of gcc the order where library references are placed, is important, so I suggest, to ensure compatibility, placing those references at the end of the command:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libserial.so.1 -o lib/libserial.so.1.0 build/arm/wavegen.o build/arm/serial.o -lm
```

I have tested in PC (gcc v.8.3.0) and in ARM (gcc v.4.6.3).