# Compiling a library that uses another library in C++

Tags: c++, c

I don't quite understand how the compilation of a library that uses another library work. From what I understand the is 4 cases :

1) Compiling a static library (A) that uses a static library (B) : The compilation would work, but linking against library A would not work because a static library is just an archive containing the .o files resulting from the compilation of A, and not from B. Is it true that when creating a static library, the compilation phase searches for function definition and find them in the header. At the linking phase, the compiler searches for function implementations in the library B and the compilation is successful if it finds them but it doesn't actually put the function implementations in the static library A. And that's why when linking against A it doesn't work

2) Compiling a static library that uses a dynamic library : I think both the creation of A and the use of A would work, but why is that? What does the compiler actually put in the dlls/so?

3) Compiling a dynamic library that uses a static library : Would this work?

4) Compiling a dynamic library that uses another dynamic library : Would this work too?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: All of these combinations will work, what are your actual doubts about that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Regarding that situation you describe in 1) post a [MCVE] please that reproduces the exact error (and post the error text verbatim).

Comment: **(1)** Building a static library doesn't involve a linker; there is no "linking phase" in that scenario. Library B is not consulted in any way. Same with scenario **(2)**.

Comment: There is no such thing as "static library that uses another library". A static library is an archive of objects that may or may not have unresolved references. How to satisfy these references is for the library user to decide.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you create a library or program in C or C++, the build process consists of two steps:

1. Compiling each C/C++ file into an object file
2. Linking the object files and creating library or executable (If you create a static library, it isn't really *linking*; but let's use this word for simplicity.)

**Compliation**

If you *compile* code that makes use of a library, you need header files (.h) for the library. They declare the public functions and classes in the library. You don't need to binary files for compilation.

**Linking**

For the *linking* step, you then need the binary file of the static or dynamic library (.lib or .a for static libraries, .dll or .so for dynamic libraries).

**Dependencies between libraries**

If you *create a static library*, all your object files will be put into a new library file. Nothing from the consumed library (static or dynamic) will be included. But it will be needed when somebody uses your library. So your library isn't self contained.

If you *create a dynamic library and consume a static library*, the necessary code from the static library will be included into your dynamic library. The new dynamic library will be self contained as far as the consumed library is concerned.

If you *create a dynamic library and consume a dynamic library*, only a reference to the consumed library will be included. So to run the final product, both the new and the consumed library will need to be available.

Comment: Thanks! It's a lot clearer now. I always wondered where people learn details like that.

Comment: Many years of experience, piece by piece, all kinds of sources: books, manuals, web, investigating and observing things...