# Compiler using LD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: compiler-errors, path, linker, shared-libraries

Is this possible? From what [I could gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path), the compiler should look for libraries in the directories given in LIBRARY_PATH when compiling, but this code I was compiling was complaining that it couldn't find a library until I set the path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I know I'm not giving any concrete information yet, but I wanted to check my hypothesis first:

What I'm trying to compile is an executable that uses lib1.so, which in turn uses lib2.so. Is it possible that it looks for lib1.so (which is the one directly linked to the executable) in LIBRARY_PATH, whereas it looks for lib2.so (which is used by the linked library but not linked directly) in LD_LIBRARY_PATH? In any case: is this common behavior or is it a sign that there is something awkward in the library dependencies in my makefile?

EDIT: Compilation commands for the library

```
[list of objects] -fPIC -shared -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/' -l2.so -o lib1.so
```

Comment: You could link `lib2.so` when compiling `lib1.so`

Comment: What do you mean? I am linking lib2.so when compiling lib1.so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. A simplified version of the compilation line for lib1.so would be: `[list of objects] -fPIC -shared -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/'  -L/lib2.so -o lib1.so`

Comment: No, should be `-l2` or `/full/path/to/lib2.so`, not `-L/lib2.so`

Comment: BTW, you should edit your question to show the actual compilation commands.

Comment: I miss-wrote when transcribing, but things are as you say (the actual libraries are not called like that, It got mixed up when I changed the name). I will add it to the question anyway in case the detail lies somewhere else in the parameters (and will consider erasing the comment).