# How to avoid errors when linking C++ shared libs into C programs

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, autotools

I'm using a library that comes with the usual AutoTools generated `configure && make && make install` procedure. The library contains a main (shared) library and some tools and is mostly written in C.

Now I am running into a problem, where one of the builds of one of the tools fails when using an instrumenter (Score-P which wraps compiler calls to do its magic).

I narrowed it down to the following facts:

libMain uses C files and 1 C++ file, C files get compiler with gcc and C++ file with g++. The library gets linked with g++ as a shared lib.
binTool uses C files only but links against libMain.

This works without the instrumenter. However when used, it adds extra libs when linking with g++ that use C++ features. Linking binTool with gcc then gives `undefined reference to 'operator delete[](void*)'` (and a few similar ones)

First: Could someone explain to me, why I have to be careful when linking against a shared library (use g++ even though the binary is only using C code)? I was under the impression, that linking of shared binaries is finalized so linking that should not pull in any new dependencies or that the dependencies are already resolved (in this case `libMain` would know it needs `libc++` and have it already referenced/stored/whatever-elf-is-doing)

Second: From reading the AutoTools docu I found that the linker for a program is chosen based on its source files. As `libMain` uses a C++ file it is linked with g++. `binTool` uses C files only hence it is linked with gcc. But `binTool` links also `libMain` which was C++-linked and seems to require to be linked with g++.
So where is the culprit? Is it AutoTools issuing the wrong linker command for `binTool`? Or should g++ have done something different when linking `libMain`?

For reference: `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)`

`ldd libMain`:

> linux-vdso.so.1
>   librt.so.1
>   libpthread.so.0
>     libm.so.6 
>     libc.so.6
>   libgcc_s.so.1
>   libdl.so.2
>     libnuma.so.1
>         libltdl.so.7

Comment: Your question is unclear, and should have some [MCVE]. Notice that on Linux a shared library can be linked with another one (when you build that library). In particular, you can (and probably should) build `libMain` by linkling it with `libstdc++`

Comment: BTW, if `libMain` is open source, you'll better name it (and gives its URL) in your question, and you might make a bug report on it

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108) very related answer

Comment: Good idea, I normally do but in this case I failed to create a MWE. I didn't try at first because it would be complex (including at least 4 different files built into 2-3 libraries and a binary) But after researching **why** I failed to create a MWE (it did not reproduce the described behavior) I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (TL&DR jump down to the fat **SOLUTION**):

The situation was far more difficult than I thought. What happens is: 
`binTool` links to shared library `libMain` which links to a shared library `libExtraCxx`.

- `binTool` is a C program, hence linked with gcc
- `libMain` contains a C++ file and is hence linked with g++. But it does not use any C++ library features so the linker omits `libstdc++` from the `libMain` link process.
- `libExtraCxx` is a C library intended to be linked into C programs by means of an automatic wrapper script. As `libMain` uses g++ it gets `libExtraCxx` linked in. This library is supposed to intercept the C++ `new`/`delete` calls and does so by using the GNU `-wrap` linker command and internally defines  (manually) mangled versions of `new`/`delete` prefixed by `__wrap_` and declares mangled versions of those prefixed by `__real_`.

Usually this works, because when a C++ linker would be used by `binTool` the wrapper would issue the `-wrap` commands and the `libstdc++` provides the `__real_` functions.

However the mistake is, that the `libstdc++` does never get linked: `libExtraCxx` is a C library that just hooks into C++ functions. `libMain` does not use any C++ library functions and `binTool` is again a C program and no shared library linked into it has `libstdc++` linked into that.

So one could point to 2 problems:

1. `libExtraCxx` should have been a C++ library and links `libstdc++` but I guess this "tricks" are done to explicitly avoid the dependency on a C++ library so it can be used by the GNU, Intel or Clang C++ compiler which might have different standard libraries.
2. `libMain` should have `libstdc++` **not** omitted. This can usually be done by passing `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the compiler/linker as explained [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7979).

I can't change `libExtraCxx` due to the amount of work involved, but I can pass arguments to the compiler, so I went with 2.

However simply doing `configure <...> LDFLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed` did not work. The flag was used but `libstdc++` was not present.

I found the culprit to be libtool which is used by `libMain`: [libtool 2.4.2 does not pass the flag at the right position](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2012-11/msg00002.html) AFAIK this bug#12880 is not fixed yet, so I was searching for more.

**SOLUTION**
I found a [hack here](https://gitlab.lrde.epita.fr/vcsn/vcsn/commit/0889b77aa96bc5101a0bf9d8b526fe8f04638ad0): Simply use `CXX="$CXX -Wl,--no-as-needed"`. This basically makes libtool think, that the flag is part of the compiler command and it won't reorder it leaving it at the beginning.

For reference: I was using starPU so `libMain` was actually `libstarpu-1.2.so`. The failed binary (`binTool`) is `starpu_perfmodel_display`. The "fake"-C++-Library is from Score-P `libscorep_adapter_memory_event_cxx.so.5` I just changed the names to simplify them.

For SCORE-P the solution is a bit more complicated as one cannot simply change CXX. So full solution to compile starPU with ScoreP is:

`SCOREP_WRAPPER=off ~/Downloads/starpu-1.2.3/configure  --prefix /usr/local CC=scorep-gcc CXX=scorep-g++ FC=scorep-gfortran --with-mpicc=scorep-mpicc --with-mpifort=scorep-mpif77`
And
`make SCOREP_WRAPPER_INSTRUMENTER_FLAGS="--opencl --thread=pthread" SCOREP_WRAPPER_COMPILER_FLAGS="-Wl,--no-as-needed"`

Explanation: `SCOREP_WRAPPER_COMPILER_FLAGS` will cause the wrapper to pass the flags to the compiler. As libTool is using the scorep wrapper it does not even see those flags so they get transparently added.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, you can link a shared library (when *building* that library) with another one. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108) answer for details. Read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

Probably, you should re-configure and re-compile and re-build your `libMain`. You want to link it *explicitly* with `-lstdc++` .

Perhaps passing some `LDFLAGS=-lstdc++` or `LIBES=-lstdc++` to the `configure` of that `libMain` might help. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Variables.html#Defining-Variables).

BTW, there are some autoconf-ed libraries coded in C++ and callable from a pure C program (for example [`libgccjit`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)), and they are linked with `-lstdc++`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that did not help. Using `g++` implies `-lstdc++` so no change due to that. I even found libTool doing something like `g++ -nostdlib ... -lstdc++` In any case the library did not show up in `ldd` which I found due to it being removed as supposedly unused.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to accomplish your problem is to write a wrapper library which its header is in `C` and the body internally is compiled with `C++` compiler so that it can call your `C++` library functions.

Later you can link your `C++` library with its `C` header to your application

Comment: `libMain` uses (partially) a C++ compiler and links with `g++` Besides that it is C-only (especially the headers) so this doesn't work. The main problem visible from the question is, that this (partially) C++ library does not contain a reference to `libstdc++`