# gcc: Not able to create .so from object files

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I am trying to create .so dynamic library from *.o files and facing below issue.

**LOG:**

```
[nptemp-static]$ gcc -shared *.o -o libexample.so

/usr/bin/ld: bindings_hubbub_parser.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
bindings_hubbub_parser.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea? Do I need to recompile my whole source code with the option specified?

Actually, I am not aware of the source code which I compiled because all the source code is open source which I downloaded and compiled by following instructions in README.

Comment: `ld` gives you the exact solution in the error message: `recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: You mean recompiling the source code again? means while running make do I need to specify the option -fPIC?

Comment: @jerry not while running make, your makefile should pass it to the compiler when creating the object files. You don't  need it for a static library. In [my own build system](https://github.com/Zirias/zimk), I solve the problem by having different names for the object files, the ones intended for a shared library are suffixed `_s.o`. Of course, that's just one possible way to handle it.

Comment: Yeah, Felix... I did the changes in make file. I am able to get dynamic library now. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create .so dynamic library from *.o files and facing below issue.

This is not that simple. In practice, you should compile *specifically* when making a shared [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries), at least on Linux.

<sup>(Perhaps you might need to edit your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) or configure somehow your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) if it was not designed for building a shared library; if building some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) library, you might ask help from its authors or community)</sup>

Shared libraries want to have [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). So you need to compile their source code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) the `-fPIC` flag passed to `g++` or `gcc` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108)). You could also want to explicit the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

Read Drepper's paper: [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Comment: Thanks...I have added the -fPIC under CFALGS variable. Able to build .so library. Now I just want to know the version of that library.. How can we get he version of that library.

Comment: That should go into your question (and probably another one), not here. And again, you need to give a lot more details (in particular, what exact library are you building). The notion of version is library specific.