# shared libraries not found while running the executable, even the shared library exists in the specified path

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries, ldd, buildconfig

I am trying to run an executable in Ubuntu 16.04. but it is giving me below error.

**error while loading shared libraries: libswscale.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

```
   :~/ga-projects/gaminganywhere-master/bin$ ldconfig -v
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/home/u0020243/ga-projects/myprog/gaminganywhere/deps.posix/lib:
    libavformat.so.56 -> libavformat.so.56.40.101
    libx265.so.79 -> libx265.so.79
    libavfilter.so.5 -> libavfilter.so.5.40.101
    libswresample.so.1 -> libswresample.so.1.2.101
    libpostproc.so.53 -> libpostproc.so.53.3.100
    libavdevice.so.56 -> libavdevice.so.56.4.100
    libswscale.so.3 -> libswscale.so.3.1.101
    libavcodec.so.56 -> libavcodec.so.56.60.100
    libavutil.so.54 -> libavutil.so.54.31.100
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu:
    libisc-export.so.160 -> libisc-export.so.160.0.0
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.23.so
    libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
    libsmartcols.so.1 -> libsmartcols.so.1.1.0
    libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.23.so
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.23.so
    libply.so.4 -> libply.so.4.0.0
    libparted.so.2 -> libparted.so.2.0.1
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.23.so
    libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.3
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libssl.so.1.0.0 -> libssl.so.1.0.0
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.23.so
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.23.so
    libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
    libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0
    libply-splash-graphics.so.4 -> libply-splash-graphics.so.4.0.0
    libiptc.so.0 -> libiptc.so.0.0.0
    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
    libnl-genl-3.so.200 -> libnl-genl-3.so.200.22.0
    libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.22.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    ld64.so.2 -> ld-2.23.so
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.1
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.23.so
    libjson-c.so.2 -> libjson-c.so.2.0.0
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.23.so
    libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
    libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.23.so
    libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.54.0
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.23.so
    libatm.so.1 -> libatm.so.1.0.0
    libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libprocps.so.4 -> libprocps.so.4.0.0
    libip6tc.so.0 -> libip6tc.so.0.1.0
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.23.so
    libapparmor.so.1 -> libapparmor.so.1.4.0
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
    libply-splash-core.so.4 -> libply-splash-core.so.4.0.0
    libdns-export.so.162 -> libdns-export.so.162.1.3
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
    libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.2
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
    libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.2
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    libseccomp.so.2 -> libseccomp.so.2.2.3
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
    libply-boot-client.so.4 -> libply-boot-client.so.4.0.0
    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.23.so
    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
    libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.23.so
    libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.23.so
    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.24
    libulockmgr.so.1 -> libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
    libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libip4tc.so.0 -> libip4tc.so.0.1.0
    libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
    libntfs-3g.so.861 -> libntfs-3g.so.861.0.0
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
    libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.3.0
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
    libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.3.0
    libxtables.so.11 -> libxtables.so.11.0.0
    liblzo2.so.2 -> liblzo2.so.2.0.0
    liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so
    libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.4
    libnewt.so.0.52 -> libnewt.so.0.52.18
    libaudit.so.1 -> libaudit.so.1.0.0
    libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.14.0
    libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.4
    libfdisk.so.1 -> libfdisk.so.1.1.0
    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
    libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.3
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.23.so
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.23.so
    libmnl.so.0 -> libmnl.so.0.1.0
    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.23.so
    libpci.so.3 -> libpci.so.3.3.1
/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu:
    librtmp.so.1 -> librtmp.so.1
    libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
    libisccfg.so.140 -> libisccfg.so.140.3.0
    libopts.so.25 -> libopts.so.25.16.1
    libcapnp-0.5.3.so -> libcapnp-0.5.3.so
    libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.3.0
    libx264.so.148 -> libx264.so.148
    libmpdec.so.2 -> libmpdec.so.2.4.2
    libisccc.so.140 -> libisccc.so.140.0.4
    libicutu.so.55 -> libicutu.so.55.1
    libestr.so.0 -> libestr.so.0.0.0
    libexpatw.so.1 -> libexpatw.so.1.6.0
    libgnutls.so.30 -> libgnutls.so.30.6.2
    libxcb.so.1 -> libxcb.so.1.1.0
    libXdamage.so.1 -> libXdamage.so.1.1.0
    libpcrecpp.so.0 -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
    libmircore.so.1 -> libmircore.so.1
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 -> libboost_system.so.1.58.0
    libogg.so.0 -> libogg.so.0.8.2
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 -> libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 -> libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
    libxcb-render.so.0 -> libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
    libXrender.so.1 -> libXrender.so.1.3.0
    libdbus-glib-1.so.2 -> libdbus-glib-1.so.2.3.3
    libgbm.so.1 -> libgbm.so.1.0.0
    libitm.so.1 -> libitm.so.1.0.0
    libxcb-present.so.0 -> libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
    libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
    libdns.so.162 -> libdns.so.162.1.3
    libwind.so.0 -> libwind.so.0.0.0
    libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.165.so
    libsensors.so.4 -> libsensors.so.4.4.0
    libxvidcore.so.4 -> libxvidcore.so.4.3
    libpng12.so.0 -> libpng.so
    libisl.so.15 -> libisl.so.15.1.1
    libLLVM-5.0.so.1 -> libLLVM-5.0.so.1
    libXfixes.so.3 -> libXfixes.so.3.1.0
    libheimntlm.so.0 -> libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
    libisc.so.160 -> libisc.so.160.0.0
    libhcrypto.so.4 -> libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
    libvorbisenc.so.2 -> libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
    libprotobuf-lite.so.9 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
    libmircookie.so.2 -> libmircookie.so.2
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
    libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.12.1
    libhogweed.so.4 -> libhogweed.so.4.2
    libxshmfence.so.1 -> libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
    libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 -> libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0.0.5
    libGeoIP.so.1 -> libGeoIP.so.1.6.9
    libp11-kit.so.0 -> libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
    libopus.so.0 -> libopus.so.0.5.2
    liblwres.so.141 -> liblwres.so.141.0.3
    libicuio.so.55 -> libicuio.so.55.1
    libdrm_radeon.so.1 -> libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
    libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0 -> libSDL2_ttf.so
    libmircommon.so.7 -> libmircommon.so.7
    libiculx.so.55 -> libiculx.so.55.1
    libgdbm.so.3 -> libgdbm.so.3.0.0
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 -> libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
    libdb-5.3.so -> libdb-5.3.so
    libvorbisfile.so.3 -> libvorbisfile.so.3.3.7
    libdrm.so.2 -> libdrm.so.2.4.0
    libICE.so.6 -> libICE.so.6.3.0
    libxcb-shape.so.0 -> libxcb-shape.so.0.0.0
    libnetfilter_conntrack.so.3 -> libnetfilter_conntrack.so.3.5.0
    libpulse-simple.so.0 -> libpulse-simple.so.0.1.0
    libsemanage.so.1 -> libsemanage.so.1
    libapt-inst.so.2.0 -> libapt-inst.so.2.0.0
    libbfd-2.26.1-system.so -> libbfd-2.26.1-system.so
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
    libtasn1.so.6 -> libtasn1.so.6.5.1
    libmpc.so.3 -> libmpc.so.3.0.0
    libeatmydata.so.1 -> libeatmydata.so.1.1.2
    libicudata.so.55 -> libicudata.so.55.1
    libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.9
    libmirprotobuf.so.3 -> libmirprotobuf.so.3
    libidn.so.11 -> libidn.so.11.6.15
    libaccountsservice.so.0 -> libaccountsservice.so.0.0.0
    libXinerama.so.1 -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0
    libdrm_amdgpu.so.1 -> libdrm_amdgpu.so.1.0.0
    libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
    libarchive.so.13 -> libarchive.so.13.1.2
    libk5crypto.so.3 -> libk5crypto.so.3.1
    libjsoncpp.so.1 -> libjsoncpp.so.1.7.2
    libtheora.so.0 -> libtheora.so.0.3.10
    libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.9
    libgio-2.0.so.0 -> libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libasan.so.2 -> libasan.so.2.0.0
    libXcursor.so.1 -> libXcursor.so.1.0.2
    libX11-xcb.so.1 -> libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
    libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.9
    libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0 -> libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
    libapt-pkg.so.5.0 -> libapt-pkg.so.5.0.0
    libXss.so.1 -> libXss.so.1.0.0
    libkrb5.so.3 -> libkrb5.so.3.3
    libpulse.so.0 -> libpulse.so.0.19.0
    libcc1.so.0 -> libcc1.so.0.0.0
    libnettle.so.6 -> libnettle.so.6.2
    librtas.so.1 -> librtas.so.1.3.13
    libpcreposix.so.3 -> libpcreposix.so.3.13.2
    libustr-1.0.so.1 -> libustr-1.0.so.1.0.4
    libkj-0.5.3.so -> libkj-0.5.3.so
    libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
    libFLAC.so.8 -> libFLAC.so.8.3.0
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libasprintf.so.0 -> libasprintf.so.0.0.0
    libedit.so.2 -> libedit.so.2.0.53
    libmirclient.so.9 -> libmirclient.so.9
    libtic.so.5 -> libtic.so.5.9
    liblber-2.4.so.2 -> liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
    libprotobuf.so.9 -> libprotobuf.so.9.0.1
    libvpx.so.3 -> libvpx.so.3.0.0
    libglapi.so.0 -> libglapi.so.0.0.0
    libsndio.so.6.1 -> libsndio.so.6.1
    libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
    libicutest.so.55 -> libicutest.so.55.1
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 -> libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
    libcapnpc-0.5.3.so -> libcapnpc-0.5.3.so
    libnuma.so.1 -> libnuma.so.1.0.0
    libicule.so.55 -> libicule.so.55.1
    libXrandr.so.2 -> libXrandr.so.2.2.0
    libformw.so.5 -> libformw.so.5.9
    libnfnetlink.so.0 -> libnfnetlink.so.0.2.0
    libXi.so.6 -> libXi.so.6.1.0
    libbind9.so.140 -> libbind9.so.140.0.10
    libxcb-glx.so.0 -> libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 -> libSDL2.so
    libXdmcp.so.6 -> libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
    libasyncns.so.0 -> libasyncns.so.0.3.1
    libicui18n.so.55 -> libicui18n.so.55.1
    libmenuw.so.5 -> libmenuw.so.5.9
    libpcap.so.0.8 -> libpcap.so.1.7.4
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 -> libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libpcre16.so.3 -> libpcre16.so.3.13.2
    libdebconfclient.so.0 -> libdebconfclient.so.0.0.0
    libXau.so.6 -> libXau.so.6.0.0
    libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0 -> libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
    libdns-pkcs11.so.162 -> libdns-pkcs11.so.162.1.3
    libcap-ng.so.0 -> libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
    libwayland-server.so.0 -> libwayland-server.so.0.1.0
    libgssapi.so.3 -> libgssapi.so.3.0.0
    libheimbase.so.1 -> libheimbase.so.1.0.0
    libhx509.so.5 -> libhx509.so.5.0.0
    libsndfile.so.1 -> libsndfile.so.1.0.25
    libffi.so.6 -> libffi.so.6.0.4
    libwayland-client.so.0 -> libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
    libXt.so.6 -> libXt.so.6.0.0
    libroken.so.18 -> libroken.so.18.1.0
    libwayland-egl.so.1 -> libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
    libXmuu.so.1 -> libXmuu.so.1.0.0
    libubsan.so.0 -> libubsan.so.0.0.0
    libpipeline.so.1 -> libpipeline.so.1.4.1
    libxkbcommon.so.0 -> libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
    libgnutls-openssl.so.27 -> libgnutls-openssl.so.27.0.2
    libmpfr.so.4 -> libmpfr.so.4.1.4
    libcapnp-rpc-0.5.3.so -> libcapnp-rpc-0.5.3.so
    libXv.so.1 -> libXv.so.1.0.0
    libXxf86vm.so.1 -> libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
    libkj-async-0.5.3.so -> libkj-async-0.5.3.so
    libapt-private.so.0.0 -> libapt-private.so.0.0.0
    libicuuc.so.55 -> libicuuc.so.55.1
    libfribidi.so.0 -> libfribidi.so.0.3.6
    libtheoraenc.so.1 -> libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2
    libpcre32.so.3 -> libpcre32.so.3.13.2
    libdrm_nouveau.so.2 -> libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
    libasn1.so.8 -> libasn1.so.8.0.0
    libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.9.3
    libkrb5.so.26 -> libkrb5.so.26.0.0
    libmp3lame.so.0 -> libmp3lame.so.0.0.0
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 -> libxcb-xfixes.so.0.0.0
    libxcb-randr.so.0 -> libxcb-randr.so.0.1.0
    libgomp.so.1 -> libgomp.so.1.0.0
    liblz4.so.1 -> liblz4.so.1.7.1
    libmagic.so.1 -> libmagic.so.1.0.0
    libasound.so.2 -> libasound.so.2.0.0
    libisc-pkcs11.so.160 -> libisc-pkcs11.so.160.0.0
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 -> libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
    librtasevent.so.1 -> librtasevent.so.1.3.13
    libgdbm_compat.so.3 -> libgdbm_compat.so.3.0.0
    libSM.so.6 -> libSM.so.6.0.1
    libperl.so.5.22 -> libperl.so.5.22.1
    libatomic.so.1 -> libatomic.so.1.1.0
    libopcodes-2.26.1-system.so -> libopcodes-2.26.1-system.so
    libX11.so.6 -> libX11.so.6.3.0
    libxcb-sync.so.1 -> libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
    libpanelw.so.5 -> libpanelw.so.5.9
    libvorbis.so.0 -> libvorbis.so.0.4.8
    libsasl2.so.2 -> libsasl2.so.2.0.25
    libkrb5support.so.0 -> libkrb5support.so.0.1
    libyaml-0.so.2 -> libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
    libgirepository-1.0.so.1 -> libgirepository-1.0.so.1.0.0
    libtheoradec.so.1 -> libtheoradec.so.1.1.4
    libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0
/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/mesa-egl:
    libEGL.so.1 -> libEGL.so.1.0.0
    libGLESv2.so.2 -> libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/mesa:
    libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0
```

My shared library path is already set in the **ld.so.conf.d** and  I am also able to see all my shared libraries when I run the **ldconfig -v**.

I tried some answers from stack overflow but no result. below are the steps I did

1. used **ldd** command on the executable. below is the terminal output for that

   :~/ga-projects/gaminganywhere-master/bin$ ldd ga-client 
       linux-vdso64.so.1 (0x00003fffb0040000)
       libga.so => /home/u0020243/ga-projects/gaminganywhere-master/bin/libga.so (0x00003fffafff0000)
       libswscale.so.3 => not found
       libswresample.so.1 => not found
       libpostproc.so.53 => not found
       libavdevice.so.56 => not found
       libavfilter.so.5 => not found
       libavcodec.so.56 => not found
       libavformat.so.56 => not found
       libavutil.so.54 => not found
       libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0 => not found
       libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => not found
       libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00003fffafe50000)
       libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00003fffafe20000)
       libXtst.so.6 => not found
       librt.so.1 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/librt.so.1 (0x00003fffafdf0000)
       libpthread.so.0 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/libpthread.so.0 (0x00003fffafdb0000)
       libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00003fffafb80000)
       libm.so.6 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/libm.so.6 (0x00003fffafa90000)
       libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00003fffafa50000)
       libc.so.6 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/libc.so.6 (0x00003fffaf860000)
       libswscale.so.3 => not found
       libswresample.so.1 => not found
       libpostproc.so.53 => not found
       libavdevice.so.56 => not found
       libavfilter.so.5 => not found
       libavcodec.so.56 => not found
       libavformat.so.56 => not found
       libavutil.so.54 => not found
       libXtst.so.6 => not found
       libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00003fffaf810000)
       libdl.so.2 => /opt/at10.0/lib64/power8/libdl.so.2 (0x00003fffaf7e0000)
       /opt/at10.0/lib64/ld64.so.2 (0x00003fffb0060000)
       libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00003fffaf7c0000)
       libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00003fffaf790000)
2. set the path of shared libraries folder in /etc/environment.

I am out of ways and, Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Satya

Comment: How do you compile and link your executable? P.S. Post text, not images.

Comment: Don't use pictures from outside. Copy the text of the error into your question. Read about [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094901/841108) to a related question. See also answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910/841108) question

Comment: @Drop Sorry, I edited my question by replacing images with text. the code is in cpp and have make file to compile it. you can check the code from below link.  https://github.com/chunying/gaminganywhere

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch from my question it is clear that ldconfig is listing all the required shared libraries. And I am using Powerpc. is this is causing the problem?

Comment: No, `ldd` lists many unresolved libraries (not found). You need to fix that. It is not PowerPC specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the path to the so file to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and check if the executable picks it up and works fine.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=pathToFolderWithLib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

./"executable"

Reference: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: Hi, this way it is working. but setting LD_LIRARY_PATH is preferred way?

Comment: @SatyaHarish Like mentioned in the link, it can be used in special conditions when nothing else is feasible but is not the preferred way. We are using this in Production and gets the job done for our requirement.

Also have you tried to set the path to your libraries in /etc/ld.so.conf  instead of /etc/ld.so.conf.d ? (Run ldconfig -v after this.)

Comment: I tried setting the path at ld.so.conf file directly. but same result as before.