# How to link symbol from shared object B into shared object A

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-linking

Current I'm  building a shared object library using the following command

```
gcc -I ../include ../../ModuleBDef/include -I ../../ModuleB/include -I ../../ModuleADef/include --shared -fPIC moduleA.c plat_linux.c -o moduleAlib.so
```

I have `moduleBlib.so` that contains a symbol that are required by `moduleAlib.so`. When I use `nm` to look at the symbols in `ModuleAlib.so` I can see a `U` beside that symbol.

I tried adding `-L` command but the symbol is still undefined.

```
gcc -I ../include ../../ModuleBDef/include -I ../../ModuleB/include -I ../../ModuleADef/include -L../../ModuleB/src --shared -fPIC moduleA.c plat_linux.c -o moduleAlib.so
```

How do I resolve this undefined symbol?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking a shared library with another shared lib in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424494/linking-a-shared-library-with-another-shared-lib-in-linux)

Comment: @frippe looks like my problem was simpler then the link you provided. My naming library convention was incorrect...

Answer (score 1):

First of all Linux convention is to start library names with `lib` prefix so your `moduleXlib` should be `libmoduleX`. Then you can link `libmoduleB.so` by adding `-lmoduleB` after the `-L ../../ModuleB/src` option.

Comment: that seemed to be my problem... Thanks...